# Is it possible to run the next job automatically if the previous job runs manually [GitLab CI]

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

my goal is, when I want to run **unit-test-job** manually, the next job **deploy-job** will run automatically. I want to create a rule looks like this:
when previous job (unit-test-job) runs manually -> the deploy job will run again

```yaml
stages:        
  - test
  - deploy

unit-test-job:
  stage: test 
  script:
    - echo "Running unit tests... This will take about 60 seconds."
  allow_failure: true
  
deploy-job:    
  stage: deploy 
  environment: production
  script:
    - echo "Deploying application..."
    - echo "Application successfully deployed."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add `when: manual` to the `test` stage, so it will run only if you start it manually. In this case the pipeline will wait for an input to start the stage and further steps will wait for this to complete.

```
stages:        
  - test
  - deploy

unit-test-job:
  stage: test
  when: manual 
  script:
    - echo "Running unit tests... This will take about 60 seconds."
  allow_failure: true
  
deploy-job:    
  stage: deploy 
  environment: production
  script:
    - echo "Deploying application..."
    - echo "Application successfully deployed."
```

EDIT

So, try to add `rules` instead of `when`. You can add multiple conditions and run or skip a stage based on this:

```
rules:
  - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME =~ /^feature/ && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
    when: never
  - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME =~ /^feature/
    when: manual
    allow_failure: true
  - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME
```

Take a look at [official documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#rules).

Comment: In my case, I want the pipeline to run automatically, but if for example, the test stage fails, I want to run only the job unit-test-job manually, and when I run it manually and finish, the next job should run automatically.

Comment: take a look at rules, as per edit